# Water wave lens and imaging

Tags: optics, waves, water

Since shallow water can refract water waves, I assume a "sea wave lens" could be constructed by rising sea level.

Could wave sources on the sea surface then be "imaged"? I.e. projected onto an array of detectors (placed after the lens) which would count waves like camera sensors count photons? Obviously 1D image instead of 2D.

Has anything like that been attempted?

If possible, then how big of an aperture would be needed for sufficient resolution to image something the size of a ship making waves... say 100 km away?

What are the limitations? Signal:noise ratio?

Could a sparse synthetic aperture be constructed the size of continental shore? Like they do with radio interferometry and atomic clocks. What resolution would be possible then?

Comment: When you say imaging the surface do you mean detecting the surface gravity waves on top of the water by acoustic sensors that are placed on the (shallow) sea floor?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/news/2005/051010/full/051010-7.html

Comment: hyportnex, yes surface gravity waves caused by wind or ships or earthquakes etc.but not specifically by acoustic sensors. Doesn't matter how you count the waves as they propagate at individual detector.

Comment: mmesser314, that link is interesting and to the point. Though the application there is to focus the energy of the waves for power generation.
I'm after something a bit more fine.
I.e. could we construct a precision lens or even a series of lenses that will sort the waves like expensive camera lenses sorts light waves so their source can be projected onto a CMOS/CCD sensor.

Comment: Obviously sea surface is two dimentional, so it's projected image would be one dimensional. Vs. light sources in 3D space being projected onto 2D sensor array.

Answer (score 0):

Variations in sea floor depth do act as lenses to focus the energy of tsunamis onto specific parts of the distant shoreline.

For example, submarine earthquakes in the pacific basin send waves towards the west coast of the US, and submarine ridges running roughly east-west will focus those waves to strike the coast at certain locations. This occurred in the tsunami that hit Crescent City in northern California in the 1960s and similar tsunami focusing occurred throughout the western Pacific and Indian oceans during the big earthquake that hit Japan ~10 years ago.

Comment: That's interesting. But using an artificially constructed lens (of sufficient size), could the waves be sorted and projected to make an image of whatever caused the waves? I had also maybe a more continuous and calm source of waves in mind than earthquakes and tsunamis... maybe like ships. Tsunami is the photography equivalent of one violent pulse of light that saturates or breaks the camera sensor.

Comment: Or is there some fundamental difference between surface water-waves and EM-waves/sound-waves that prevents that? Obviously the scale is different and ocean surface is 2D, not 3D space.